# How do I select distinct records?

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite table with column `number` that may have duplicates.

How can I select records which get distinct rows by number?

```
SELECT 
    contacts_table._id AS _id, 
    title, title_short,  
    DISTINCT number, 
    note, 
    categories, 
    contacts_categories_name, 
    contact_id, 
    contacts_categories_catalog_id 
FROM contacts_table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts_categories_table 
    ON(contacts_categories_contact_id = contact_id 
        AND contacts_categories_current_user = current_user)  
WHERE ((current_user = ? AND saved =? 
    AND ( title LIKE ? OR  number LIKE ? OR note LIKE ? )) 
    AND (contacts_categories_catalog_id = ? )) 
ORDER BY 
    contacts_categories_name = 'UNSORTED' DESC,
    contacts_categories_name ASC, 
    title ASC
```

Comment: What about the other columns' values? When there are multiple rows with the same `number`, from which one should they come?

Comment: @CL. except '_id' and 'contacts_categories_catalog_id' all other columns are the same. Thus, taking first row and ignoring others will work well. For particulat query it does not metter, which 'contacts_categories_catalog_id' will be returned, any fill fit as long ast it present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(contacts_table._id) AS _id,
    title,
    title_short,
    number,
    note,
    categories,
    contacts_categories_name,
    contact_id,
    MIN(contacts_categories_catalog_id)
FROM ...
GROUP BY
    number
ORDER BY ...;
```